# View that calls endpoint?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the REST framework package for Django. I am trying to create a way to handle a POST request when a follow button is pressed. So far on the API View side I have this:

```
class FollowToggle(APIView):
    def post(self, id=None):
        target      = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)
        follower    = self.request.user

        if follower.is_authenticated():
            if follower in target.followers.all():
                target.followers.delete(follower)

            else:
                target.followers.create(follower)

        data = {
            "success": 1
        }

        return Response(data)
```

Now what I'd like to do is using my ProfileView, I'd like to handle POST requests by executing the APIView I created with the specific parameters. How do I do this?

```
class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = User
    slug_field = 'username'
    template_name = 'accounts/profile.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
           //Call the API with the parameters
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you want to use same logic at more than one place then you should refactor it to a separate module, something like this:

```
def follow_unfollow(follower, id):
    target = get_object_or_404(User, id=id)

    if follower.is_authenticated():
        if follower in target.followers.all():
            target.followers.delete(follower)
            return False
        else:
            target.followers.create(follower)
            return True

    return False
```

Then you can use this module at both places[follow toggle api and profileView]

If you want to call the followToggle api, then you can use the `reverse` to get the url of followToggle api and then make a POST request to that endpoint

Comment: Hmm, I see. This could be the backend code for users who don't have JavaScript enabled and if they do the REST framework endpoint URL would be used, correct?

Comment: Maybe yes, depends upon your implementation and need.

Comment: I see what your saying. So for example, if I call the URL endpoint I would still be calling the same function in the API View and same goes for the profile view correct?